# Transpose data in R multiple variables (preferrably with tidyverse or stargazer)

Tags: r, tidyverse, transpose, stargazer

I've seen similar looking topics, but none seem to have exactly what I'm looking for. Apologies if this is a repeat question.

From my tidyverse function, I've been able to produce the following:

```
  locationAndYear  var1 var2  var3        var4  var5   var6
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 City 2015       0.425 0.412 0.854       0.844 0.853  0.368
2 City 2016       0.270 0.259 0.842       0.834 0.856  0.456
3 City 2018       0.468 0.454 0.816       0.833 0.848  0.430
4 City 2019       0.336 0.604 0.842       0.852 0.887  0.525
```

I just want to transpose this such that the table looks like this, so that I can present it in an RMarkdown document. (perhaps there is a better way to do this in stargazer)

```
  variable     City 2015  City 2016   City 2018   City 2019
  var1             0.425      0.270       0.468       0.336
  var2             0.412      0.259       0.454       0.604
  var3             0.854      0.842       0.816       0.842
  var4             0.844      0.834       0.833       0.852
  var5             0.853      0.856       0.848       0.887
  var6             0.368      0.456       0.430       0.525
```

This is basically for a report - so ultimately would like to do this in a nice table format like stargazer.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Just be careful with stargazer. There was a somewhat serious bug found recently, and I'm not sure if it has been fixed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553731/r-why-does-stargazer-return-incorrect-values-for-min-and-max-with-this-datafram/61554323#61554323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get data in long format and then wide :

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -locationAndYear, names_to = 'variable') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = locationAndYear, values_from = value)

# variable  City_2015 City_2016 City_2018 City_2019
#  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 var1      0.425     0.27      0.468     0.336
#2 var2      0.412     0.259     0.454     0.604
#3 var3      0.854     0.842     0.816     0.842
#4 var4      0.844     0.834     0.833     0.852
#5 var5      0.853     0.856     0.848     0.887
#6 var6      0.368     0.456     0.43      0.525
```

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = 'locationAndYear'), 
      variable~locationAndYear, value.var = 'value')
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(locationAndYear = c("City_2015", "City_2016", 
"City_2018", "City_2019"), var1 = c(0.425, 0.27, 0.468, 0.336
 ), var2 = c(0.412, 0.259, 0.454, 0.604), var3 = c(0.854, 0.842, 
0.816, 0.842), var4 = c(0.844, 0.834, 0.833, 0.852), var5 = c(0.853, 
0.856, 0.848, 0.887), var6 = c(0.368, 0.456, 0.43, 0.525)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! This does it